# mouse programming in gcc in linux

Tags: linux, gcc, mouse

We know that we can use int 33h (51) in DOS and write functions like `resetmouse()` as `r.x.ax=0000; int86x(0x33, &r, &r); return r.x.ax` in all applications using DOS interrupts on DOS and Windows. Similarly in gcc in Linux, I am seeking for already built in functions or writing mouse interface in `gcc` on Linux. If `gcc` provides or any other open software provides these functionality. It is well and good. To make this more precise: I want to select a point to draw a circle or a rectangle etc. and my input will be through mouse clicks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Track keyboard and mouse events in C on linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472585/track-keyboard-and-mouse-events-in-c-on-linux)

Answer (score 1):

With linux you grab a pseudo-file (pseudo = fake) which is a raw access to the mouse. It is not recommended to redo what has already been done. You should look at libgpm which supports many kind of pointing devices : http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/4600

Anyway many libraries can handle both mouse and screen access.

You can have a look at svgalib, which offer direct screen functions and mouse grab.
But this don't seem be be maintained since 1999 :
http://www.svgalib.org/

SDL seems to be a better one as many games are using it :
http://www.libsdl.org/

Allegro is a crossplatform "game" library which can also draw and grab mouse :
http://alleg.sourceforge.net/